# OpenPop.NET error read email

Tags: openpop

I have a error, how I solve this?

ERROR:The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. what's meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this caused by an HTML-formatted email retrieved from a Lotus Notes server. It is likely that the email message you are accessing has a character in it that doesn't work with Base64. My email had one of the characters from this page in it as a phone number delimiter from a foreign country:

http://www.alt-codes.net/

Once I forwarded the email with that character removed, the component worked fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In namespace OpenPop.Mime.Decode at class Base64:
After : base64Encoded = base64Encoded.Replace("\r\n", "");
Inset : if (base64Encoded.StartsWith("=")) base64Encoded = base64Encoded.Substring(1, base64Encoded.Length - 1);

Comment: Please learn how to [format the text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Maybe also try adding some explanation.